# In Javascript, how do you stop running a script file in the middle without using throw?

Tags: javascript

In a Javascript file, how can I tell to stop run the rest code?

For example,

```
if (typeof $==="undefined") return;
```

return doesn't work as it can only be used in a function.

I don't want to throw an exception either.

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Comment: _"I don't want to throw an exception either"_... why not?

Comment: wrap the whole code in an IIFE ... or ... `if (typeof $ !== "undefined") { rest of code here }`

Comment: I prefer to always have at least a `main` function.

Comment: It's not duplicate.answers on the other question can't do it. It seems the conclusion is it's not possible without using throw. I don't want to use throw as it'll throw an exception which it isn't. I return it on purpose.

Comment: The trick is to prevent reporting the throw, shown as `window.addEventListener('error', function (e) {e.preventDefault();e.stopPropagation();}, false);` in the accepted answer of the duplicate. Note `throw` doesn't need to throw an exception, it can throw any value you want, including one that a try/catch block around `main` could identify, suppress global error reporting and rethrow another (or same) value to return to the event loop.